# Got Google Maps API working on Android without Google API build

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I can get my android application to have google maps api v2 working on it fine even though I was building my application using API 8, not Google API + Android API 8

so the question is, if I can get google maps to work fine with my android application without needing to compile/build with the Google Api+Android 8, so what is Google API build used for then ?

It's a very confusing thing

Comment: what device did you run the application on?

Comment: HTC Desire, what difference does that make ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Maps Android API v1 required the Google API's add-on. V2 doesn't need the add-on and is supported via [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html). This is the new way Google is allowing developers to access their API's. The advantage to this is that Google Play Services can be update via the Google Play Store. I think it is much harder for Google to update the add-on. You can see what else the add-on supports here: https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/. Mainly the maps API plus some USB API's.